# Recording and saving sound from Flash AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, recording

How can I record and save sound in flash AS3. I have writing access to the server and also access to PHP files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you have to stream the audio from the user to a Flash Media Server or Red5 server and save it there.

This is one question i would love to find out i am wrong.

Comment: Yes but as I understand you can only record audio from the microphone. I want to record any sound that is played. 
Is there any way to attach SoundChannel to the netstream or something like that?

Comment: aahhh, sorry - i misunderstood. Looks like you might be able to access sound sample data during playback. See this audiomixer.. http://flash.mediabox.fr/index.php?showtopic=94758

Answer (score 0):

1. Record the data locally
2. compress them to mp3
3. send the bytearray to the server to be saved

Answer (score 0):

As of FP10 you can save files without the need for a server side.

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Save_a_file_locally_with_Flash_Player_10-14426.html