# Recording from the sound card in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I've seen this issue pop up in other forms but I haven't been able to get a straight answer: using ActionScript 3, is it possible to capture sound input directly from the sound card? I'm not talking about the microphone; I mean recording what audio is actually coming out of a user's computer (like the Stereo Mix program on Windows).

I've seen questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372364/recording-and-saving-sound-from-flash-as3) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121609/how-to-capture-sound-from-the-line-in-device), and even this interesting post [here](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=211661), and I'm thinking that what I'm asking isn't possible with this technology, but I haven't gotten a definitive "yes" or "no", so I'm hoping someone here can help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, flash ads cannot listen to your system (for the good). Not even AIR apps can do that. Microphone/Camera classes only.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is over 4 years old, but I want to add that I was able to successfully capture audio from the sound card by enabling Stereo Mix and plugging speakers into the sound card.

Follow the instructions here to enable stereo mix: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/39532/how-to-enable-stereo-mix-in-windows-7-to-record-audio/

Then, in your audio settings, set the default playback device to the speakers, and set Stereo Mix as the default recording device.

*Do not* enable "Listen to this device" on the "Listen" tab, this will cause a fun echo effect.

Test your setup by playing some audio. If you see the level indicator lighting up green on the Stereo Mix icon, you've got it all set up correctly.

In AS3, when you grab a reference to the microphone, you'll see that the name is "Stereo Mix."

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks :)