# AS3: Recording sound as they are output/played

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

I understand how to record microphone input in AS3 from [this doc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d1d.html).

Is it possible to record sound exactly as they are being output/played?
The reason is I applied some sound transform (via the global SoundMixer) to sounds that are currently playing; and I also want to record this sound data while it is being played.

I just saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411830/recording-from-the-sound-card-in-as3), to clarify, I am not trying to record just all sounds on the user's computer (which is not possible). My flash app has a Youtube player in it (via their AS3 API), and it's playing some sounds. I applied transforms using SoundMixer.soundTransform, and I want to record what's being played when the user is playing it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just a passing suggestion.. on my desktop it seems ABLE to record sound into Flash from a different tab playing Youtube (HTML5).. I don't know how it's doing that!!

- I allow microphone here.. (none actually plugged in, and speaker out has in-ear headphones)
  http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-useful-audio-recorder-app-in-actionscript-3--active-5836

PS: Anyone trying this must reduce Windows volume since anything above 10-20% is distorted audio into the Flash app.

- And this HTML5 youtube trailer was recorded fine into the Wav file produced by Flash app above
  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVt32qoyhi0

So after a quick search it seems my Realtek Audio is classed as a **Full-Duplex** soundcard and also within its own control panel I have an option called "Multi-streaming" which is enabled/ticked. I think Full-Duplex is enough to do this though. Try options within your  soundcard's own settings software. Don't know about your end-users. Some hardware will do it, some wont, there is no all-round solution outside of AIR (which makes desktop apps out of your AS3 code).